# Proving that function composition is non-commutative using a counter example

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $A$ be a set and consider $G=\{f:A \rightarrow A : \text{f is a bijection}\}$. I'm trying to prove that G is a non-commutative group with respect to composition. However I'm not quite sure how to prove that it's not commutative. I heard that using a counter example is the easiest way but I can't find a counter example that would satisfy $G$. If $A=\mathbb R$ then it would be easy to find a counter example but since we're just told that $A$ is a set and nothing more I'm not exactly sure how to find a counter example.

Comment: Actually you have to make some hypothesis concerning the cardinal of $A$ (does it contain at least $3$ elements or not ?)

Comment: @charMD Yeah I've already made that hypothesis when proving that $G$ is associative, has an identity and inverse element. But I'm still not sure how I wold go about proving that it's non-commutative. Would I, for instance, have to create 2 functions which uses those 3 elements and show that their composition is non-commutative?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea : given three elements $a, b, c$, try to find two functions swapping $a, b$ and swapping $b, c$

Comment: @charMD I tried to find two functions which would swap $a,b$ and $b,c$ but I wasn't exactly sure what you meant by "swapping". Do you mean that I should define two functions s.t. $f(x) = \begin{cases} b & \text{if $x=a$} \\ c & \text{if $x=b$} \\ a & \text{if x = c}\end{cases}$
and  $g(x) = \begin{cases} a & \text{if $x=a$} \\ b & \text{if $x=b$} \\ c & \text{if x = c}\end{cases}$ ?

Comment: @charMD Sorry I meant to say $f(x) = \begin{cases} a & \text{if $x=b$} \\ b & \text{if $x=a$} \\ c & \text{if $x=c$} \end{cases}$
and
$g(x) = \begin{cases} a & \text{if $x=a$} \\ b & \text{if $x=c$} \\ c & \text{if $x=b$} \end{cases}$

Comment: Yes indeed, $f(g(a))=b$ but $g(f(a))=c$ with $f, g$ as in your last comment

Comment: @charMD Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the set of all bijections from a set A to itself is denoted $perm(A)$, its set of permutations.  It's useful to know that $perm(A)$ is a group under composition.

First your claim is not true if the cardinality of $A$ is $1$ or $2$.  The compositions will be commutative.  If $|A| \geq 3$ then it is the case that the compositions are non commutative.  Test this out by letting $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and picking some permutations explicitly.  Now if $|A| > 3$, then $perm(A)$ will contain $perm(\{1,2,3\}$ as a subset(subgroup) and since these will not commute with each other, certainly $perm(A)$ will not be commutative.

Comment: It's also not true if $|A|=0$. :)